# How to read keyboard state in Swift / MacOS?

Tags: swift, macos, keyboard, event-handling

I'm writing a game in Swift 3 for Mac OS. I'd like to be able to do "as long as the A key is down, move to the left". In other environments I'm used to a function like KeyIsDown('A'), but I can't find it here.

Does it exist, or do I need to watch every keydown and keyup event and keep track of the state myself? I will be wanting to do this for arrow keys as well as alphabetic keys.

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to observe the key be pressed, set some internal state indicating it's been pressed, and only exit that state when the key has been released.

Comment: NSResponder has only two method for keyboard handling keyDown and keyUp. See the doc here :https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1525805-keydown. So, the solution would be as @BallpointBen mentioned already.

Comment: Writing a game meaning what!?  Using SpriteKit, SceneKit or just UIView?

Comment: Using SceneKit with a SpriteKit overlay for a HUD of scores, time, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to BallpointPen, for a clear answer. So I'll just keep a table of key state for every keycode, and switch bits on an off as keyDown and keyUp events come in.

Answer (score -4):

Depending on you use `UITextview` or `UITextfield`. So, conforming `UITextviewDegelate` or `UITextfieldDegalate` there are some degelate methods that can change keyboard state.

Comment: The question is asking about macOS which does not have `UITextView` and `UITextField`